# Where's the system-wide zshrc file located on macOS?

Tags: macos, zsh

What's the location of the system-wide `zshrc` file on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system-wide zshrc is nominally /etc/zshrc.

That's the path that zsh runs at startup, and you can run it, edit it (subject to file permissions; see discussion under ma11hew28's answer), etc under that path, but its actual location in the filesystem is a bit more complicated (and depends on the version of macOS you're using). Firstly, in all versions of macOS, /etc is a symbolic link to /private/etc, so in versions 10.0 through 10.14, that's the file's actual location.

In version 10.15 (Catalina), a new complication is added by the [split-volume format](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367158/whats-system-volumes-data) Apple is using to protect system files. In 10.15 (and presumably later versions), /private is [firmlinked to /System/Volumes/Data/private](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/10/11/macos-catalina-boot-volume-layout-revised-for-10-15-release/), so the file's actual location is now /System/Volumes/Data/private/etc/zshrc.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer, I got the idea to `man zsh` and found the sections `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` and `FILES`, which elaborate on the first sentence of your answer. And thank you for providing that extra info about the macOS filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

```
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/zshrc
```

I found that path by running:

```
find /System/Library -name "*zsh*" 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: That's not the live file that's actually run, just a template. I'm not sure exactly how it is used, but presumably it's used to create the live file (see my answer) at some point.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, good call. Thanks. For me both files have the same data (`diff -q /System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/zshrc /etc/zshrc`) but different inodes (`ls -1i /System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/zshrc /etc/zshrc`). I guess it's sort of like [PostgreSQL's `template0` database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html). If I ever messed up `/etc/zshrc`, I could always just `sudo cp /System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/zshrc /etc/zshrc`, assuming I've kept `/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/zshrc` the same since installing macOS.

Comment: It's interesting. I did a little more digging, and found that /System/Library/Templates is new in Catalina, and I presume it's there precisely as a source for setting up the corresponding files on the Data volume. The "live" versions are generally editable (as root), but the /S/L/Template directory is on the read-only system volume, so not changeable (without extreme measures). I don't know when the Template versions get copied over the "live" versions, but it may be that they'll be reset to Template during things like system updates. So I learned something; have a +1!

Comment: @GordonDavisson, interesting. Thanks. Also, I just noticed that if I wanted to edit my `/etc/zshrc`, I think I'd have to run `sudo chmod 644 /etc/zshrc` first (because the file permissions of my `/etc/zshrc` are `-r--r--r--`). Then after editing and saving (as `root`) `/etc/zshrc`, I'd run `sudo chmod 444 /etc/zshrc` to change the file permissions back. Nice. Thanks for the +1! :-) I learned a lot. I didn't even know [about the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650), so thank you.

Comment: Hah, I semi-noticed the perms on /etc/zhsrc, but didn't think much about it. I was test-editing it in `vi`, so when it refused to save to a read-only file I just did `:w!`, and `vi` discovered that (since it was running as root) it could indeed save changes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, nice. :-) I didn't know vi could do that. So I guess I wouldn't need to change the file permissions first. Thanks.